# Convert "with" statement to "try" statement

Tags: python, with-statement, magic-methods, try-except

I wonder how `with` statements work. I am trying to convert the following:

```
with obj() as o:
    do_something()
```

into this:

```
o = obj.__enter__()
try:
    do_something()
except Exception as e:
    obj.__exit__(type(e),e, **I don't know what should be here**)
else:
    obj.__exit__(None, None , None)
```

So how it will be? If I am wrong in anywhere, please correct me. I want to know what to replace the 
`**I don't know what should be here**` with.

Comment: [PEP-343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement) provides the conversion you are trying to write.

Comment: Thanks you,I will read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [PEP-343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement), which introduced context managers, the code

```
with obj() as o:
    do_something()
```

is equivalent to

```
mgr = obj()
exit = type(mgr).__exit__
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
exc = True

try:
    try:
        o = value
        do_something()
    except:
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
finally:
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

Some notes:

1. We don't write `o = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)` because the name `o` is only defined if `__enter__` does not raise an exception, allowing us to enter the `try` statement at all. (There are other ways to handle this, but this is how I interpret PEP-343's translation.)
2. `__exit__` can be called in two different places. If we catch an exception, we pass information about that to `__exit__`, which can prevent the calling code from seeing it if it returns `True`.
3. The `finally` block ensures that `__exit__` is called exactly once. Namely, we want to call it if no exceptions were raised, but not again if the first call swallowed an exception by returning `True` or raised an exception itself.

Comment: Thank you. This is real answer.

Answer (score 1):

If just as a learning experiment this is fine. I don't think it shouldn't actually be used. You generally shouldn't need to call Python's magic methods directly.

You really want to call `__exit__` in a `finally` block. The three arguments that you want to provide to `__exit__` can be obtained by calling `sys.exc_info`.

```py
import sys

o = obj.__enter__()
try:
    do_something()
finally:
    obj.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())
```

Comment: Yes, it is for understand with statement really , not for using try instead of with statement

Comment: This is not quite the same; see PEP-343. Namely, the `__exit__` method can suppress any exceptions raised by `do_something` if it returns `True`.